# Error on creating instance with GPU on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gpu, nvidia, createinstance

I have increased the GPU quotas (Preemptible NVIDIA K80 GPUs) in region us-east1 via request. [image: GPU quotas] However, I still can not create the instance with GPUs and get the error message saying Quota NVIDIA_K80_GPUS exceeded no matter I try zone us-east1-c [image: us-east1-c] or us-east1-d. [image: us-east1-d] I have contacted them but it charges $150/month for technical support. Please let me know if you need additional info to troubleshooting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out preemptible GPUs are not the same as (regular) GPUs.[image: figure] Based on my multiple experiments, one has to use [preemptible VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance) in order to carry the preemptible GPUs. Don't mess up these two while sending the quota request.